# getJSON - Loading Image Gallery From Public Server - Flickr

Tags: getjson, flickr

I have tried so many URL variations for Flickr and all attempts have failed to load my image gallery into my own webpage.

I am pretty sure its the URL. If I replace the URL with:

```
"api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?jsoncallback=?"
```

all works fine to load public photos from Flickr, but to load my own album (URL below), it won't work.

Yes I have a valid API from Flickr. I also checked the script syntax in "jsbin.com" and all of that is good.

Can anyone help resolve this?

***Here is the jQuery script:***

```js
(function() {
  var flickerUrl = "https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?&method=flickr.people.getPublicPhotos&api_key=<removed by edit>&user_id=135938131@N02&format=json&jsoncallback=?";
  $.getJSON(flickerUrl)
  .done(function(data) {    
     $.each(data.items, function(i, item) {

     var image =    $("<img>")
           .attr("src", item.media.m)
           .attr("title", item.title);

        $("<a>")
           .attr("href", item.link)
           .attr("target", "_blank")
           .html(image)
           .appendTo("#images");        

        if ( i === 8 ) {
           return false;
        }
     });
  });
})
();
```

***HTML***

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />

   <title>Flickr Image Gallery</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css" />
</head>
<body>

   <h1>Natural Scenery</h1>

   <br>

   <div id="images"></div>

 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script src="./js/flickrgallery.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ive edited your post and removed your api key (waiting approval). You shouldn't post such things here, since anyone is able to abuse it.

Comment: @user3375051 - even if [your edit](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/10167342) is accepted, the [history](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/33606066/revisions) *before* your change is still visible, plus your suggestion of replacing it with `<removed by edit>` brings attention to the fact that the edit history will expose the old value. Not sure what best to do here. Maybe a wandering moderator could intervene, if it's actually that important?